# Nested Lambda expression instead of foreach

Tags: c#, lambda, foreach

```
class A{
    public B body { get; set; }
}

class B{
    public List<C> positions { get; set; }
}

class C{
    public string NameOfWeek { get; set; }
}

class week{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NameOfWeek { get; set; }
}

class SomeX{
    public List<A> MapWeekID(List<week> weekList, List<A> AList)
        {
            foreach (var a in AList)
            {
                foreach (var position in a.body.positions)
                {
                    position.NameOfWeek = weekList
                        .Where(x => x.NameOfWeek.ToString() == position.NameOfWeek)
                        .Select(y => y.NameOfWeek)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                }
            }

            return AList;
        }
}
```

Here is code.
How to write lambda for above foreach statement? I am trying but couldn't get hold of best solution so can anyone?

Comment: Linq is *not* very good when you want to *modify* an *existing* collection (`AList`). I suggest keeping `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

*Linq* and *Extension Methods* shouldn't really try to solve everything. However, if you really need everything in the one statement, you could use this.

```
AList.SelectMany(x => x.body.positions)
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(
         position => 
            position.NameOfWeek = weekList.Where(x => x.NameOfWeek == position.NameOfWeek)
                                          .Select(y => y.NameOfWeek)
                                          .FirstOrDefault());
```

***Note** : If this came across my desk for code review, I'd send it back with a note asking for a refactor.*

Basically, your original `foreach` is easy to read and maintain. It's not trying to be too fancy, and you can easily see what's going on. These qualities are way more important then getting everything in one statement.

Comment: Thank you for your positive comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use the linq function SelectMany. Here is a modified version:

```
foreach(var position in AList.SelectMany(k => k.body.positions)) {
    position.NameOfWeek = weekList
                        .Where(x => x.NameOfWeek.ToString() == position.NameOfWeek)
                        .Select(y => y.NameOfWeek)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```